# How does the redox reaction in a voltaic battery pile start?

Tags: redox

From the Wikipedia article, the redox reaction for a [voltaic pile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltaic_pile) is:

\begin{align}
\text{Oxidation:} && \ce{Zn &-> Zn^{2+} + 2e^-}\\
\text{Reduction:} && \ce{2H^+ + 2e^- &-> H2}\\
\text{Total:}     && \ce{Zn + 2H^+ &-> Zn^{2+} + H2}
\end{align}

What is causing the reaction to take place?  It seems that the zinc anode must be oxidized and lose electrons, which travel through the anode/cathode wire to the copper cathode.  Is the reduction of the ionized hydrogen at the cathode causing this?  Also, how is the hydrogen ionized?

[image: a]

Comment: [Don't abbreviate Wikipedia as Wiki!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_abbreviate_%22Wikipedia%22_as_%22Wiki%22!)

Comment: Water already has hydrogen ions in it: water auto-ionizes. Acidic solutions, e.g., vinegar, lemon juice, hydrochloric acid, have significantly higher concentrations of hydrogen ions. Place a solid piece of zinc metal in vinegar or lemon juice, and it will spontaneously react (get oxidized, i.e., corrode away) as shown in your equations. You would see little hydrogen bubbles on the zinc. The voltaic pile just lets you get electrical energy rather than useless heat energy.

Answer (score 1):

You are right ! It is difficult to believe that in the voltaic cell (zinc and copper plates separated by a neutral $\ce{NaCl}$ solution), the cathodic reduction may be due to the reduction of $\ce{H+}$ ions into $\ce{H2}$, because a neutral solution has practically no $\ce{H+}$ ions : $\ce{[H+] = 10^{-7} M}$. The cathodic reduction is not $$\ce{2 H+ + 2 e- -> H2}$$ It must be
$$\ce{2 H2O + 2e− -> H2 + 2 OH^− }$$ As a consequence, $\ce{H2}$ bubbles do appear on the copper plate. But the $\ce{OH-}$ ions created at the cathode react with the $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions created at the anode according to : $$\ce{Zn^{2+} + 2 OH-  ->  Zn(OH)2 (s)}$$ so that a precipitate of $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$ appears in the solution. To go back to Nick's question, the final equation is not the reaction $$\ce{Zn + 2 H+ -> Zn^{2+} + H2}$$ as proposed in the text, but it is $$\ce{Zn + 2H2O -> Zn(OH)2 + H2}$$

Comment: $2e^-$ is an antecedent to the product.  Where are those electrons coming from such that the reaction is started?

Comment: The two electrons are coming from the metallic $\ce{Zn}$ atom. $\ce{Zn}$ is more stable as an ion than as a neutral atom. In other words, it looks as if the neutral zinc atom "feels like" losing two electrons. Pardon me this image. But zinc can do this only if some other ion, atom or molecule does accept its electrons, here $\ce{H2O}$

Comment: Thanks. Why is it that the two electrons leave the anode and enter the cathode, vs simply leaving the anode and reacting with H2O?

Comment: Probably the electrons are repelling one another in the anode. And they prefer leaving the anodic zone, rather than reacting with $\ce{H2O}$near the anode. I am not sure. I would be pleased to hear another device.

Comment: This answer is misleading.  It's true that there are not a lot of H+ ions in water *at equilibrium*, however this ignores that if any of these ions are consumed, they will be immediately replaced to maintain equilibrium, so there is effectively an "unlimited supply" of them even if they're not all present initially.  Electrons cannot "react" with (neutral) H2O directly.  H2O naturally dissociates into H+ and OH- and then H+ combines with electrons.  However, Zn++ ions being produced at the anode will repel H+ ions, so there will be none at the anode for the electrons to come in contact with.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that both electrode reactions:

\begin{align}
\ce{Zn &<=> Zn^{2+} + 2e^-}\\
\ce{2H^+ + 2e^- &<=> H2}\\
\end{align}

are reversible and are ongoing even without galvanic connection of the anode and the cathode.

Rates of electrode oxidation reactions increase with the electrode potential and rates of electrode reduction reactions decrease with potential. Each redox system has some particular equilibrium potential value where the rate of the net reaction is zero.

When anodes and cathodes are galvanically connected, they force each to other different then equilibrium potential, what leads to non-zero net reaction, free electron production/consuption and the current.

Zinc anode forces lower than equilibrium potential on the hydrogen cathode and $\ce{H+(aq)}$ reduction reaction takes the upper hand.

Hydrogen cathode forces higher than equilibrium potential on the zinc anode and $\ce{Zn(s)}$ oxidation reaction takes the upper hand.